# Erro ao fazer requisição no javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-service, xml, get

Estou tentando fazer um requisição neste formato

```
 $.get("http://meuurl.com/webservice", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Mas Recebo este erro

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

Comment: `$.get` utilize **dataType** e segue https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ .. se pode tentar `$.ajax` também

Answer (score 1):

Sua requisição está saindo do browser com sucesso.
No entanto, algum erro do lado do servidor está ocorrendo. Normalmente, o erro 500 é um simples `NullPointerException`.

Caso você não consiga identificar o erro no servidor, você pode editar sua pergunta adicionando o código do lado do servidor e o log do erro. Assim, poderemos te ajudar com mais efetividade.

Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição.

Comment: Onde posso visualizar o log no visual studio, tentei habilitar o MessageLoggin e o Tracing no Web.Config mas não aparece nada no Output Debug

Comment: Natanel, qual linguagem você está usando? Poderia editar a pergunta e colocar mais sobre o seu código?